# Errors within SQL-View with INNER JOINS and CASES

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view, sapb1

I want to create an sql query which will return a view with these fields:

 `s.ItemCode, s.ItemName, s.ItmsGrpCod, s.ItmsGrpNam, t.Name, t.FormulaResult_Cost`

---

`t.FormulaResult_Cost` will be calculated with this formula:

```
CASE WHEN IsNull(T3.U_VAR5, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND(((T0.AvgPrice * T3.U_VAR1 * T3.U_VAR2) + T3.U_VAR3) * T3.U_VAR4 / IsNull(T3.U_VAR5, 0), 5) END AS FormulaResult_Cost
```

The variables (`U_VAR4`, `U_VAR5` etc), are in a *user defined table* called `dbo.[@Z_VARIABLES]`

---

The query that I wrote is :

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT s.ItemCode, s.ItemName, s.ItmsGrpCod, s.ItmsGrpNam, t.Name, t.FormulaResult_Cost
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT T0.ItemCode, T0.ItemName, T0.ItmsGrpCod, T1.ItmsGrpNam
               FROM   dbo.OITM AS T0 INNER JOIN
                              dbo.OITB AS T1 ON T0.ItmsGrpCod = T1.ItmsGrpCod
               WHERE (T0.QryGroup10 = 'Y')) AS s INNER JOIN
                   (SELECT T0.ItemCode, T3.Name, CASE WHEN IsNull(T3.U_VAR5, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND(((T0.AvgPrice * T3.U_VAR1 * T3.U_VAR2) + T3.U_VAR3) 
                                   * T3.U_VAR4 / IsNull(T3.U_VAR5, 0), 5) END AS FormulaResult_Cost
                    FROM   dbo.[@Z_VARIABLES] AS T3 CROSS JOIN
                                   dbo.OITM AS T0) AS t ON s.ItemCode = t.ItemCode
ORDER BY s.ItemCode
```

---

This query, works perfectly if I have only ONE formula for every category (`t.Name` : field of `[@Z_VARIABLES]`).

---

Now I want to have different formula for every category. 

So, i tried to do it with this code:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT s.ItemCode, s.ItemName, s.ItmsGrpCod, s.ItmsGrpNam, t.Name, t.FormulaResult_Cost
FROM  (
        (SELECT DISTINCT T0.ItemCode, T0.ItemName, T0.ItmsGrpCod, T1.ItmsGrpNam
        FROM   dbo.OITM AS T0 INNER JOIN
               dbo.OITB AS T1 ON T0.ItmsGrpCod = T1.ItmsGrpCod
        WHERE (T0.QryGroup10 = 'Y')) AS s INNER JOIN          
            (SELECT * FROM dbo.[@Z_VARIABLES] AS T3 CROSS JOIN dbo.OITM AS T0,
                (CASE t3.Name
                    WHEN 'KOUZINES' THEN
                        SELECT T0.ItemCode, T3.Name, CASE WHEN IsNull(T3.U_VAR5, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND(((T0.AvgPrice * T3.U_VAR1 * T3.U_VAR2) + T3.U_VAR3)  * T3.U_VAR4 / IsNull(T3.U_VAR5, 0), 5) END AS FormulaResult_Cost
                        FROM   dbo.[@Z_VARIABLES] AS T3 CROSS JOIN dbo.OITM AS T0
                    WHEN 'NYPTIRES' THEN
                        SELECT T0.ItemCode, T3.Name, '3.333' AS FormulaResult_Cost
                        FROM   dbo.[@Z_VARIABLES] AS T3 CROSS JOIN dbo.OITM AS T0
                    WHEN 'PATOUDES & KAPPAKIA' THEN
                        SELECT T0.ItemCode, T3.Name, '4.444' AS FormulaResult_Cost
                        FROM   dbo.[@Z_VARIABLES] AS T3 CROSS JOIN dbo.OITM AS T0
                    ELSE
                       SELECT T0.ItemCode, T3.Name, '11.11' AS FormulaResult_Cost
                       FROM   dbo.[@Z_VARIABLES] AS T3 CROSS JOIN dbo.OITM AS T0
                END)
            ) AS t ON s.ItemCode = t.ItemCode
)
ORDER BY s.ItemCode
```

---

And this query, has many errors, such as:



```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 42
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: yes, as this errors says, you have several `AS` in your code. Like this `AS T0 AS t `. I think you should remove all this `AS t`

Comment: @Darka , I edited my code after your explanation of the error... I changed the `AS`. The errors changed but still i am confused about what I have to do to correct my code. Is there a logic problem or a syntax problem? See above pls

Comment: all this case `CASE t3.Name` is in wrong place. You can use one `SELECT` from this `CASE` and put same `CASE` logic on `FormulaResult_Cost` column

Comment: but I already have one select * from **table to use for case parameter** , **this case** . I just don't know if I writing all this correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I mean you can rewrite it more simpler:

```
  (SELECT * FROM dbo.[@Z_VARIABLES] AS T3 
    CROSS JOIN dbo.OITM AS T0
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT T0.ItemCode, T3.Name
                , CASE t3.Name
                     WHEN 'KOUZINES' THEN     CASE WHEN IsNull(T3.U_VAR5, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND(((T0.AvgPrice * T3.U_VAR1 * T3.U_VAR2) + T3.U_VAR3)  * T3.U_VAR4 / IsNull(T3.U_VAR5, 0), 5) END
                     WHEN 'NYPTIRES' THEN '3.333' 
                     WHEN 'PATOUDES & KAPPAKIA' THEN '4.444'
                     ELSE '11.11'
                  END AS FormulaResult_Cost
                FROM   dbo.[@Z_VARIABLES] AS T3 CROSS JOIN dbo.OITM AS T0
                )
```

This is not tested. Can find some bugs.
And also I don't know all your logic, but for me it looks like to many `CROSS JOINS`, but like I said, don't know logic.

Comment: I did what I want. thank you very much. I couldn't manage to simplify it that much.